# AutoDesk View and Data API - return position of selected element

Tags: javascript, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

**Question:**

I've been using the AutoDesk View and Data API, and I've been curious to know if it was possible to return geometric information about a selected element. Ideally, I want the position, size, angle, type of shape, etc., of a selected element so that I could compare, for instance, two lines. I don't mind how this information is represented, so long as two shapes could be compared.

**Objective:**

If there was a line, such that (psuedo-representation):

(x1=0,y1=0),(x2=10,y2=0), a 2d straight line of length 10;

and another line, such that:

(x1=20,y1=20),(x2=30,y2=20), another 2d straight line of length 10.

Then I would be able to say that these two lines are similar from this information and deduce their angle. There would obviously need to be some indication of the type of entity that is selected also. That's the desired outcome of my question.

**What I've tried:**

So far, I've found several useful functions within Viewer3d.js, but none seem to return any data about the geometric position of a single selected shape:

```
Viewing.Extension.SomeExtension = function (viewer, options)
{
    ...

    var shapeRenderData = viewer.impl.getRenderProxy(viewer, dbId);
    var shapeFragmentData = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer, dbId);
}
```

I already understand how to include the onSelect event, and that is left out for clarity of the question.

Both of these return a JSON object with properties of `fragId, scale, quaternion` and `position` - although with exception of fragId, these properties have null values.

**Extra:**

I am basing the extension I've created off of this GitHub tutorial from the AutoDesk team:

https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/tutorial-getting.started-view.and.data/blob/master/chapter-3.md#Step5

Please note the fifth step includes code for the onSelect event I'm discussing, should you wish to recreate the question to help me solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've wrote that blog post about geometry snapping and selection commands. I think it should provide some elements of answer to your question:

[Geometry snapping and selection commands with View & Data API](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/09/geometry-snapping-and-selection-commands-with-view-data-api.html)

Comment: To all those who come across this answer - it's not spoonfed like most of SO, but it's a damn good lesson in properly devised extensions for VAD and better understanding the geometry in the API! Thank you for this. Also, during the time passed since asking, I found that Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getSubItemsWithProperties provides some gold for digging further into document geometry.